# Change empty strings to Null or "None" ssp class with PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ssp

How to convert empty string to Null or "Nothing" when the column appears in the datatable.
For example, in the brand column, there are many empty strings. So, i wanted to change it to null or "None".

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'name',      'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'brand',     'dt' => 2 ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'end-date',
        'dt'        => 3,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'jS M Y', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'id',
        'dt'        => 4,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="proDelete.php?id=' . $d . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this item?\')">Delete</a>';
        }
    ),
);

$where = "end-date< CURDATE()";
// Include SQL query processing class
require( 'ssp.class.php' );

// Output data as json format
echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $dbDetails, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $where)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a function like you do it in other columns:

```php
array(
    'db' => 'brand',
    'dt' => 2,
    'formatter' => function($d, $row) {
        return $d !== '' ? $d : 'Nothing';
    }
),
```